# npm install angular/cli version:1.4.10

Tags: angular, angular-cli, npm-install

I train myself via a book. This book requires @angular/cli-Version 1.4.10 to be installed.

I install it locally via:  **npm install @angular/cli@1.4.10 -–save-dev**

Then I run **npm list --depth=0**  and I get the following result

```
`-- @angular/cli@1.4.10

npm ERR! peer dep missing: ajv@^6.0.0, required by ajv-keywords@3.2.0
npm ERR! missing: mkdirp@0.5.1, required by node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
npm ERR! missing: minimist@0.0.8, required by mkdirp@0.5.1
npm ERR! missing: minimatch@3.0.4, required by ignore-walk@3.0.1
...............
```

What is going wrong? Why are not all dependencies installed?

Comment: There is no 1.4.10 version. The latest 1.4.x is 1.4.8, and dates from Oct. 2017. You'd better train yourself with the latest version of the CLI and of Angular, otherwise you'll learn obsolete stuff.

Comment: The command "npm view  @angular/cli versions" lists "1.4.10" as available. Additionally the "npm list --depth=0" shows that it is really installed locally. But some dependencies are missing

Comment: Still, there have been a lot of versions since then, including a makor Angular version. Don't learn obsolete stuff.

Comment: I think i agree with JB Nizet you should learn the newest version. The errors you are getting are the peer dependencies missing which means there are a libraries you are currently using which have some depemdencies that you haven’t installed. You can easily solve this problem by installing those particular dependencies

Comment: But isn't the command --save-dev instead of -save-dev?

Comment: The command is --save-dev of course. I corrected my text. But, nevertheless, I expected that dependencies are installed automatically (as usual for any other packages) !?

Comment: Some of the dependencies will not work as that version is very outdated and they now require a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You first open your cmd  and type this command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@version
for example npm install -g @angular/cli@7
```

Then you can see the angular version using the command `ng version`

Now go to the folder where you want to install angular and following this command:

```
ng new projectname
```